# How to Call Fragment another fragment function

Tags: android

I created a TabLayout with one MainActivity and two fragments in Android.

But how do you get the second Fragment to receive the button event and call the first Fragment function?

I tried the following but it does not work and I ask.

```
public interface CustomSearchPOI {
    void requestSearch(String query);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        customSearchPOI = (CustomSearchPOI)context;
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement CustomSearchPOI");
    }
}
```

Second Fragment Code

```
if(info_cursor != null) {
        info_cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!info_cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            if(info_cursor.getInt(0) == id) {
                out_subject.setText(info_cursor.getString(1));
                out_college.setText(info_cursor.getString(2));
                out_classroom.setText(info_cursor.getString(3));
                break;
            }
            info_cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    choice_dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Location_navigate), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            TabsFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            customSearchPOI.requestSearch(out_college.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    choice_dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.tt_modify), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            update_timetable_dialog(id);
        }
    });
    choice_dialog.show();
```

Call function Code

```
@Override
public void requestSearch(String query) {
    String FRAGMENT_TAG = "LOCATION_TAG";
    Fragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    try {
        ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG)).searchPOI(query);
    } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("[TAG]", fragment.getTag());
    }
}
```

MainActivity Code

```
public void searchPOI(String query) {
    query = Searchcheck(query);
    TMapData data = new TMapData();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
        data.findAllPOI(query, new TMapData.FindAllPOIListenerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFindAllPOI(final ArrayList<TMapPOIItem> arrayList) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tMapView.removeAllMarkerItem();
                        for (TMapPOIItem poi : arrayList) {
                            addMarker(poi);
                        }
                        if(arrayList.size() > 0) {
                            TMapPOIItem poi = arrayList.get(0);
                            moveMap(poi.getPOIPoint().getLatitude(), poi.getPOIPoint().getLongitude());
                            if(poi.getPOIPoint().getLatitude() > 36.832311 && poi.getPOIPoint().getLongitude() < 127.165038) {
                                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.No_place), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if(location_me.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
                                    location_me.hide();
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                            dst = new TMapPoint(poi.getPOIPoint().getLatitude(), poi.getPOIPoint().getLongitude());
                            searchRoute(src, dst);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First Fragment Code (function to call)

According to the Google development documentation, direct communication between fragments and fragments is impossible.

So when I try to call Fragment function from Fragment through Activity, I get NullPointerException error.

I used the try catch syntax to see if there was an error in the tag name or an error in the query, but neither of them was a problem.

Comment: why not create an interface in one fragment and implement it in another?

Comment: Do you also need to implement the second fragment?

But how do you move the ViewPager in the TabLayout?

Comment: better yet, since both fragmnts are in the same activity, why dont u put your method there instead?

Comment: I tried this method now, but I still get a NullPointerException error.

Am I writing the code wrong?

Comment: Define interface X in your fragment that has method Y. Implement interface X in your activity. Instantiate your interface in fragment X(dont forget to class-cast), call your method on the instance of the interface. Need code?

Comment: It's rough idea, but it's a difficult concept. I would appreciate your code.

Comment: check answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FragmentX:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    interface MyInterface{

       void doSomething();
    }

    public void someMethodInYourFragment(){
     ((MyInterface)getContext()).doSomething();//throws ClassCastException if not implemented in Activity
    }

}
```

**Class X:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
    //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code in the question column.

Is that the right code? If you do, you will get a NullPointerException error.

Comment: have you tried the above code? Post your stacktrace

Comment: Yes I have used the above code.

I have posted the modified code in the question column. (See call function code)

But I still get a NullPointerException.

Comment: where exactly? when calling the interface method?

Comment: Yes, TabsFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
           customSearchPOI.requestSearch(out_college.getText().toString()); part